# How to add multiple json object with the jq command?

Tags: json, jq

I want to edit this json file:

```
{
    "shipping_orders": [{
    }],
    "timestamp": 100,
    "shoporders": [{
        "buyer_remark": null
    }],
    "payment_channel_info": {
        "shipping_method": 28,
        "grouping_info": {
            "groups": [{
                "display_info": {
                    "discount": 1
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to add these json objects to the file:

1. `"headers": {}`
2. `"ext_ad_info_mappings": []`
3. `"enabled": true`

The output I want is like this:

```
{
    "headers": {},
    "shipping_orders": [{
    }],
    "timestamp": 100,
    "shoporders": [{
        "buyer_remark": null,
        "ext_ad_info_mappings": []
    }],
    "payment_channel_info": {
        "shipping_method": 28,
        "grouping_info": {
            "groups": [{
                "display_info": {
                    "discount": 1,
                    "enabled": true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this command but the result only shows `true` https://jqplay.org/s/0aVbFzMttK

```
jq '.+{"headers": {}} and .shoporders[] + {"ext_ad_info_mappings": []} and .payment_channel_info.grouping_info.groups[].display_info + {"enabled": true}'
```

How should I edit the json file so that it'll output like the one I want above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just locate where in the tree you want to set the values and set them.

```
.headers = {}
  | .shoporders[].ext_ad_info_mappings = []
  | .payment_channel_info.grouping_info.groups[].display_info.enabled = true
```

https://jqplay.org/s/ugF5foO90N